# Devise : Sign in from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller

I need to sign in fron non-devise controller. I found [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-from-a-controller) link from devise wiki, but I get error :

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

I did exactly like in the link. What went wrong? Thanks

My code :

```
sign_in(:site, Site.find(params["si"]))
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of signing in a User outside of the devise controller?

Comment: Find out where this method is coming from by putting this line above that call: `p method(:sign_in).source_location`. Run the tests again and now you'll see where that method is being defined.

Comment: @RyanBigg I put that above that call, and where should I see the result? I saw nothing in my console. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

```
sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id])
```

If you do a binding.pry after you'll see that current_user is set.

For some reason, doing a redirect after this will make current_user nil.

That's why I set something in the session like this and then redirect, and then check if that session id is set and then use it to do the above code:

```
session[:new_user_id] = params[:id]
```

Comment: As a code-only answer this has been flagged as low-quality and will be probably deleted soon. Please add an explanation about what this code does.

Comment: Edited it. Could you try being nicer? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it's a standard answer I copy-paste because there are many such posts like yours.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass agruments post you code for clarity

```
sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
```

Comment: I did exactly like that. but got wrong number of arguments error

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late. But had the same problem and as it turns out I had a sign_in method in my users controller.

Did you check for a sign_in method in the controller where you are calling the sign_in method?

Comment: thanks. but i already found the mistake. it was stupid mistake. but thanks anyway

Comment: How did you fix it? @ishwr