# devise authentication inside actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

**I want to sign_in my user inside my UserMailer using devise**:

Desired behavior:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  # need to include devise somehow

  def show_preview(user)
    sign_in(:user, user)
    response = RestClient.get 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts.json' #this needs authentication
    # email_body = format response ... ...
  end

end
```

**Problem:** I dont know which parts of devise I need to include in my `UserMailer`, and how to include them.

I've tried `include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers` (in order to use `sign_in`), from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342832/how-do-i-login-a-user-with-devise), but it seem to be deprecated.

**Why:** Because I want to have the same data in my email to the user, as what I show the user on the web app. So, I want to access the same api (ie `localhost:3000/api/posts.json`, which is what I use for my controlle/view, which requires that the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm using a workaround which uses `Rabl::Renderer`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  class RablScope
    include ApplicationHelper # A way to include applicationHelper in Rabl::Engine
  end

  def show_preview(user)
    # @posts = function of user
    response = JSON.parse( Rabl::Renderer.new('api/posts/show',@posts,view_path: 'app/views', scope: RablScope.new()).render )
    # email_body = format response ... ...
  end
end
```

The downside is that I have to copy paste all the logic/code from the api controller into the mailer into `# @posts = function of user` otherwise this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the request to the api before calling the mailer method and pass the data in as and argument.

You controller action could look something like this

```
def my_action
  response = RestClient.get 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts.json'
  UserMailer.show_preview(current_user, response)
  #render or redirect as needed
end
```

and you mailer could look something like this

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  # need to include devise somehow

  def show_preview(user, data)

    # email_body = format response ... ...
    @email_body = format data #this will make the data available to your view
  end

end
```

Comment: Upvoted for a good workaround in the situation i described. But in the real code base this solution is insufficient, as it will create too much of a mess. I still believe I really need to sign_in inside my mailer.